# Join the whole one dictionary data with one key of another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Dictionary 1=. { ( key1:none) }
Dictionary 2=. {(key1:value),(key2:value)..... }
Output 
Dictionary 1 = { (key1: (key1:value),(key2:value)..... }

Dictionary 1= (key1:  Dictionary 2 as value)

Key of first have all the data of dictionary 2 as values

Comment: `dictionary1['key1'] = dictionary2`? Not sure what you mean, since none of your examples, input or output, are actually valid Python code. A [MCVE] showing what you've tried, and *legal* inputs and expected outputs would be helpful.

Comment: Please do use the proper coding format by following the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, bear in mind that in Python, a key can only have a single value which means that you need to give your `key1` in `Dictionary1` the `list` of `Dictionary2`

Comment: @Law: Don't try to edit to make legal code out of the garbage code for the OP; you're making it legal at the expense of possibly changing the OP's intended question. They need to fix it, it's hopelessly ambiguous as written.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for your feedback, I am trying to help him out...

Comment: d1 = {'key1':None}
d2 = {'key1':1, 'key2':2}
d1['key1'] = list(d2.items())   output    d1 = {'key1': [('key2', 2), ('key1', 1)]}      @ShadowRanger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are trying to set the value of a dictionary (d1) with items of an other dictionary (d2) with list type.

In order to do that you can use the function `.items()` to access to the items of d2 and cast the obtained element to a `list`.

```
d1 = {'key1':None}
d2 = {'key1':1, 'key2':2}

d1['key1'] = list(d2.items())
```

Output:

```
d1 = {'key1': [('key2', 2), ('key1', 1)]}
```

Comment: Please explain what you did. Not everybody can understand your answer

Comment: d1 = {'key1':4}
d2 = {'key1':1, 'key2':2}

d1['key1'] = list(d2.items())  What can be the output? @Florian Hat

Answer (score 0):

d1 = {'key1':4}
d2 = {'key1':1, 'key2':2}

d1['key1'] = list(d2.items())

Output
{'key1': [('key1', 1), ('key2', 2)]}